# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ' ' with no type?

Tags: c++, declaration, void, iso

I am having this problem for a while now and I can't see an obvious solution .
I am trying to compile a program and I am getting an error on the following 
part of code :

```
class entry
{
private:
    int node_id ; 
    int toll[2] ; 
 public:
    entry( int );
    ~entry( void );



    int get_node_name( void ){ return node_id; };
    int* get_toll( void ){ return toll ; };
    int* get_etoll( void ){ return etoll ; };

    void entry_operate() ;
};

entry::entry( int id)
{
   node_id = id ;
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
   {
        toll[i] = 0 ;
        etoll[i] = 0 ;
   }
}

entry::~entry()
{

}

entry::entry_operate()
{

}
```

Error:
[Error] ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'entry_operate' with no type [-fpermissive]
[Error] prototype for 'int entry::entry_operate()' does not match any in class 'entry'
[Error] candidate is: void entry::entry_operate()

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the full function type:

```
void entry::entry_operate() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: And please replace `whatever foo(void);` by `whatever foo();`